# HMaster getting Aborted at startup

Tags: hadoop, hbase

Hmaster getting aborted after starting ./start-hbase.sh in hbase-0.96.0 with hadoop 2.2.0.

Tried with hbase-0.94.16 and hbase-0.98 but same result. Hmaster aborts as soon as it starts. Even tried with replacing jars in hbase lib manually as well as using maven but the issue is unresolved. Is there any other solution?

Below is the corresponding hbase-hadoop-master-hadoop-master.log...

```
2014-02-24 10:11:27,078 INFO  [Replication.RpcServer.handler=2,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: Replication.RpcServer.handler=2,port=60000: starting
2014-02-24 10:11:27,565 INFO  [RpcServer.handler=23,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.handler=23,port=60000: starting
2014-02-24 10:11:27,970 INFO  [master:hadoop-master:60000] mortbay.log: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
2014-02-24 10:11:28,172 INFO  [master:hadoop-master:60000] http.HttpServer: Added global filter 'safety' (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer$QuotingInputFilter)
2014-02-24 10:11:28,177 INFO  [master:hadoop-master:60000] http.HttpServer: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context master
2014-02-24 10:11:28,177 INFO  [master:hadoop-master:60000] http.HttpServer: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context static
2014-02-24 10:11:28,191 INFO  [master:hadoop-master:60000] http.HttpServer: Jetty bound to port 60010
2014-02-24 10:11:28,191 INFO  [master:hadoop-master:60000] mortbay.log: jetty-6.1.26
2014-02-24 10:11:29,227 INFO  [master:hadoop-master:60000] mortbay.log: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:60010
2014-02-24 10:11:29,623 INFO  [master:hadoop-master:60000] master.ActiveMasterManager: Registered Active Master=hadoop-master.payoda.com,60000,1393236677609
2014-02-24 10:11:29,629 INFO  [master:hadoop-master:60000] Configuration.deprecation: fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2014-02-24 10:11:29,851 DEBUG [main-EventThread] master.ActiveMasterManager: A master is now available
2014-02-24 10:11:30,537 INFO  [master:hadoop-master:60000] Configuration.deprecation: hadoop.native.lib is deprecated. Instead, use io.native.lib.available
2014-02-24 10:11:30,800 DEBUG [master:hadoop-master:60000] util.FSTableDescriptors: Current tableInfoPath = hdfs://hadoop-master:9000/hbase/data/hbase/meta/.tabledesc/.tableinfo.0000000001
2014-02-24 10:11:30,821 DEBUG [master:hadoop-master:60000] util.FSTableDescriptors: TableInfo already exists.. Skipping creation
2014-02-24 10:11:30,944 INFO  [master:hadoop-master:60000] fs.HFileSystem: Added intercepting call to namenode#getBlockLocations so can do block reordering using class class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.fs.HFileSystem$ReorderWALBlocks
2014-02-24 10:11:30,950 INFO  [master:hadoop-master:60000] master.SplitLogManager: Timeout=120000, unassigned timeout=180000, distributedLogReplay=false
2014-02-24 10:11:30,956 INFO  [master:hadoop-master:60000] master.SplitLogManager: Found 0 orphan tasks and 0 rescan nodes
2014-02-24 10:11:31,000 INFO  [master:hadoop-master:60000] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=192.168.14.35:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=hconnection-0x4a867fad
2014-02-24 10:11:31,012 INFO  [master:hadoop-master:60000-SendThread(hadoop-master.payoda.com:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server hadoop-master.payoda.com/192.168.14.35:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (Unable to locate a login configuration)
2014-02-24 10:11:31,617 INFO  [master:hadoop-master:60000-SendThread(hadoop-master.payoda.com:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to hadoop-master.payoda.com/192.168.14.35:2181, initiating session
2014-02-24 10:11:31,617 INFO  [master:hadoop-master:60000] zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Process identifier=hconnection-0x4a867fad connecting to ZooKeeper ensemble=192.168.14.35:2181
2014-02-24 10:11:31,620 INFO  [master:hadoop-master:60000-SendThread(hadoop-master.payoda.com:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server hadoop-master.payoda.com/192.168.14.35:2181, sessionid = 0x1446360aa4a0001, negotiated timeout = 90000
2014-02-24 10:11:31,640 DEBUG [master:hadoop-master:60000] catalog.CatalogTracker: Starting catalog tracker org.apache.hadoop.hbase.catalog.CatalogTracker@3eaa3e5b
**2014-02-24 10:11:31,684 FATAL [master:hadoop-master:60000] master.HMaster: Unhandled exception. Starting shutdown.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: .META. no longer exists. The table has been renamed to hbase:meta**
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName.valueOf(TableName.java:292)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKTable.populateTableStates(ZKTable.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKTable.<init>(ZKTable.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.AssignmentManager.<init>(AssignmentManager.java:281)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.initializeZKBasedSystemTrackers(HMaster.java:677)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.finishInitialization(HMaster.java:809)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.run(HMaster.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2014-02-24 10:11:31,684 INFO  [master:hadoop-master:60000] master.HMaster: Aborting
2014-02-24 10:11:31,711 DEBUG [master:hadoop-master:60000] catalog.CatalogTracker: Stopping catalog tracker org.apache.hadoop.hbase.catalog.CatalogTracker@3eaa3e5b
2014-02-24 10:11:31,712 DEBUG [master:hadoop-master:60000] master.HMaster: Stopping service threads
2014-02-24 10:11:31,712 INFO  [master:hadoop-master:60000] ipc.RpcServer: Stopping server on 60000
2014-02-24 10:11:31,712 INFO  [RpcServer.handler=15,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.handler=15,port=60000: exiting
2014-02-24 10:11:31,712 INFO  [RpcServer.handler=23,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.handler=23,port=60000: exiting
2014-02-24 10:11:32,129 INFO  [master:hadoop-master:60000] master.HMaster: Stopping infoServer
2014-02-24 10:11:32,138 INFO  [RpcServer.responder] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.responder: stopped
2014-02-24 10:11:32,138 INFO  [RpcServer.responder] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.responder: stopping
2014-02-24 10:11:32,304 INFO  [hadoop-master.payoda.com,60000,1393236677609.splitLogManagerTimeoutMonitor] master.SplitLogManager$TimeoutMonitor: hadoop-master.payoda.com,60000,1393236677609.splitLogManagerTimeoutMonitor exiting
2014-02-24 10:11:32,304 INFO  [RpcServer.listener,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.listener,port=60000: stopping
2014-02-24 10:11:32,304 INFO  [Replication.RpcServer.handler=2,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: Replication.RpcServer.handler=2,port=60000: exiting
2014-02-24 10:11:32,304 INFO  [Replication.RpcServer.handler=1,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: Replication.RpcServer.handler=1,port=60000: exiting
2014-02-24 10:11:32,304 INFO  [Replication.RpcServer.handler=0,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: Replication.RpcServer.handler=0,port=60000: exiting
2014-02-24 10:11:32,304 INFO  [RpcServer.handler=29,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.handler=29,port=60000: exiting
2014-02-24 10:11:32,305 INFO  [RpcServer.handler=28,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.handler=28,port=60000: exiting
2014-02-24 10:11:32,305 INFO  [RpcServer.handler=27,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.handler=27,port=60000: exiting
2014-02-24 10:11:32,305 INFO  [RpcServer.handler=26,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.handler=26,port=60000: exiting
2014-02-24 10:11:32,305 INFO  [RpcServer.handler=25,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.handler=25,port=60000: exiting
2014-02-24 10:11:32,305 INFO  [RpcServer.handler=24,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.handler=24,port=60000: exiting
2014-02-24 10:11:32,305 INFO  [RpcServer.handler=22,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.handler=22,port=60000: exiting
2014-02-24 10:11:32,305 INFO  [RpcServer.handler=21,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.handler=21,port=60000: exiting
2014-02-24 10:11:32,305 INFO  [RpcServer.handler=20,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.handler=20,port=60000: exiting
2014-02-24 10:11:32,305 INFO  [RpcServer.handler=19,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.handler=19,port=60000: exiting
2014-02-24 10:11:32,305 INFO  [RpcServer.handler=18,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.handler=18,port=60000: exiting
2014-02-24 10:11:32,305 INFO  [RpcServer.handler=17,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.handler=17,port=60000: exiting
2014-02-24 10:11:32,306 INFO  [RpcServer.handler=16,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.handler=16,port=60000: exiting
2014-02-24 10:11:32,306 INFO  [RpcServer.handler=14,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.handler=14,port=60000: exiting
2014-02-24 10:11:32,306 INFO  [RpcServer.handler=13,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.handler=13,port=60000: exiting
2014-02-24 10:11:32,306 INFO  [RpcServer.handler=12,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.handler=12,port=60000: exiting
2014-02-24 10:11:32,306 INFO  [RpcServer.handler=11,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.handler=11,port=60000: exiting
2014-02-24 10:11:32,306 INFO  [RpcServer.handler=10,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.handler=10,port=60000: exiting
2014-02-24 10:11:32,306 INFO  [RpcServer.handler=9,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.handler=9,port=60000: exiting
2014-02-24 10:11:32,306 INFO  [RpcServer.handler=8,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.handler=8,port=60000: exiting
2014-02-24 10:11:32,306 INFO  [RpcServer.handler=7,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.handler=7,port=60000: exiting
2014-02-24 10:11:32,306 INFO  [RpcServer.handler=6,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.handler=6,port=60000: exiting
2014-02-24 10:11:32,307 INFO  [RpcServer.handler=5,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.handler=5,port=60000: exiting
2014-02-24 10:11:32,307 INFO  [RpcServer.handler=4,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.handler=4,port=60000: exiting
2014-02-24 10:11:32,307 INFO  [RpcServer.handler=3,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.handler=3,port=60000: exiting
2014-02-24 10:11:32,307 INFO  [RpcServer.handler=2,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.handler=2,port=60000: exiting
2014-02-24 10:11:32,307 INFO  [RpcServer.handler=1,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.handler=1,port=60000: exiting
2014-02-24 10:11:32,307 INFO  [RpcServer.handler=0,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.handler=0,port=60000: exiting
2014-02-24 10:11:32,930 INFO  [master:hadoop-master:60000] mortbay.log: Stopped SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:60010
2014-02-24 10:11:32,945 INFO  [master:hadoop-master:60000] client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Closing zookeeper sessionid=0x1446360aa4a0001
2014-02-24 10:11:32,948 INFO  [master:hadoop-master:60000] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x1446360aa4a0001 closed
2014-02-24 10:11:32,949 INFO  [master:hadoop-master:60000-EventThread] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
2014-02-24 10:11:32,954 INFO  [master:hadoop-master:60000] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x1446360aa4a0000 closed
2014-02-24 10:11:32,954 INFO  [master:hadoop-master:60000] master.HMaster: HMaster main thread exiting
2014-02-24 10:11:32,955 INFO  [main-EventThread] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
2014-02-24 10:11:32,955 ERROR [main] master.HMasterCommandLine: Master exiting
**java.lang.RuntimeException: HMaster Aborted**
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMasterCommandLine.java:192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:2787)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you had upgrade from HBase 0.94.x to 0.96.x? They are pretty incompatible starting from migration to protobuffers as RPC mechanics and yes, changes in meta-tables approach.
Please be sure you have checked upgrade documentation.

http://hbase.apache.org/upgrading.html#upgrade0.96

Please pay special attention to ZooKeeper service.